# Computing a quality factor of multiple measurements

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, statistics

Suppose I measure the same quantity twice with two methods, first I get 0 with 0.001 uncertainty, then I get 1 with 0.000001 uncertainty. We can see from this most likely there is something wrong with the uncertainties or measurements. I am faced with such a problem, I have multiple measurements of the same quantity with prescribed uncertainties, and I would like to calculate how compatible these measurements are, or if they are correct, how unlikely it is to get those values. A quality factor or something is what I'm looking for.

What is the most sensible way to do this?

The goal is to know if there is something wrong with the uncertainties or not.

Comment: [Use a chi squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)?

Comment: You should include much more background information. E.g. how is the data distributed? Which assumptions are made during evaluation? How are the uncertainties calculated? I reckon that at least one method uses an assumption, which is not satisfied, and that the procedure is not robust against deviations from this assumption. A possible issue might be e.g. an outlier or mis-documented data-point.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the uncertainties are Gaussian distributed, then 1 is 1000 sigma away from 0 +/- 0.001. To a first approximation, you can ignore the much smaller uncertainty on 1.

You can use the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function) to determine the probability of finding a value at $n$ sigma away from the mean value (for Gaussian uncertainties).

For example,
\begin{equation}
{\rm 1 \sigma:} \ \ {\rm erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 0.3173105...\\
{\rm 2 \sigma:} \ \ {\rm erfc}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 0.0455003...
\end{equation}
By the way, the $2\sigma$ result is very close to the $p$-value of 5% used in some sciences as a threshold for statistical significance.

In your example, we want to know the probability of getting a result at 1000$\sigma$ or higher. I evaluated this on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erfc%281000%2Fsqrt%282%29%29) and got

\begin{equation}
{\rm 1000 \sigma:} \ \ {\rm erfc}\left(\frac{1000}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 4.58 \times 10^{-217151}\\
\end{equation}

Suffice it to say, it is very unlikely your two measurements differ only by a statistical fluctuation. You should be looking for a systematic error affecting one or both measurements.

Comment: We can easily get a result 1000 sigma away from the other if the uncertainty in that measurement is high, so we need to take that into account aswell

Comment: But the premise of your question is that the uncertainty on measurement 2 is absolutely miniscule. I'm answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Thats just an example, thats not the question bro. The questions have question marks at the end you know.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your question is, you gave a specific numerical example and my answer is how you would analyze that example. In general you could plot the uncertainties of the two measurements and see at what confidence level they overlap with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Measurements that use the same method can be assumed to have the same systematic error, affecting all measurements equally. So you can, for example, take an average value of these measurements or discuss the consistency of different measurements without knowing the systematic error.

However, it is not possible to compare measurements made with different methods and hence different systematic errors without knowing what these systematic errors are. For example, the two measurements in your example could be consistent with each other if one has a systematic error of $-0.5$ and the other has a systematic error of $+0.5$.

Comment: We may assume the systematic error is 0 for all methods if needed